# Animate a plot with plt.animate.FuncAnimation reusing lists

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

Given a list of points and a function, say `solution=[0,1,2,3]` and `func(x): return x*x`, is there a way to use the given solution list in the frame fuction? I have the fallowing code that works fine:

```
x_data=[]
y_data=[]

def animation_frame(i):
 x_data.append(solution[i])
 y_data.append(func(solution[i]))
 line1.set_xdata(x_data)
 line1.set_ydata(y_data)
 return line,
```

But as you can see I make another list with the same elements. I've tried to use `line1.set_xdata(solution[:i+1])` but it doesn't seem to work. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: could you provide a full working examlpe? imports, function calls & co, thanks

Comment: I'll add a colab notebook, if any doubts please tell me. Thanks. [google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Tz-8aV9mafIx0xytZ1TXVfXVyQ-NRp41?usp=sharing)